# Using row variables as columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, data-manipulation

I have the following data:

```
split2 <-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Liz\\Desktop\\R text editing\\looped\\splitne.csv")
split2
```

`TYPE VALUE
Ne      6
CI95(L) 3
CI95(U) 21
Ne      6
CI95(L) 3
CI95(U) 21
Ne      6
CI95(L) 3
CI95(U) 21
Ne      6
CI95(L) 3
CI95(U) 21`

And I want to convert it to the following format using R:

`Ne  CI95(L)    CI95(U)
6     3         21
6     3         21
6     3         21
6     3         21`

I've tried using the dcast function in the reshape2 package

```
dcast(split2, TYPE~VALUE)
```

However I end up with this, and I have no idea how to correctly assign value.var to override correctly:

`split2$TYPE 3 6 21
1     CI95(L) 4 0  0
2     CI95(U) 0 0  4
3          Ne 0 4  0`

I think I'm being daft with this dataset in regards to transforming it, I've also tried subsetting and recombining the data however I can't seem to get that to work either. Any help, or pointers in a general direction much appreciated!!

Comment: You may need `library(data.table); dcast(split2, rowid(TYPE)~TYPE)`

Comment: You're a flipping star, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a sequence column.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(split2, rowid(TYPE)~TYPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a tidy solution. This assumes that your `TYPE` values repeat:

```
library("tidyverse")

df <- tribble(
  ~TYPE, ~VALUE,
  "Ne" ,     6,
  "CI95(L)", 3,
  "CI95(U)", 21,
  "Ne"   ,   6,
  "CI95(L)", 3,
  "CI95(U)" ,21,
  "Ne" ,     6,
  "CI95(L)" ,3,
  "CI95(U)", 21,
  "Ne"    ,  6,
  "CI95(L)", 3,
  "CI95(U)", 21
)

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(id = cumsum(TYPE=="Ne")) %>%
  tidyr::spread(TYPE,VALUE) %>% 
  dplyr::select(Ne, `CI95(L)`,`CI95(U)`)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Ne `CI95(L)` `CI95(U)`
# * <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     6         3        21
# 2     6         3        21
# 3     6         3        21
# 4     6         3        21
```